# Remove Google Fonts from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor, google-webfonts

In source of website I see this code:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,400italic,500italic,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,400italic,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <style type="text/css">.
```

It doesn't have ID so I can't remove it from functions.php

Steps I have done to remove it:

1. installed plugin Disable/Remove Google Fonts, but it not helped
2. In functions.php added this function:

   ```
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){ if ((strpos($href, "//fonts.googleapis.com/") === false) || !is_page(31765)) { return $href;} return false;});
   ```

but still nothing changed.

3. disabled all plugins, changed theme to different one, but still nothing.

I really need to remove them because it adds 1 second delay to website.

**What can you suggest to remove it completely? (I use local custom fonts)**

Comment: I think you might have removed it with the tries you made. You might be seeing them due to cache, so kindly remove the cache and see it it solves. Also check the headers.php file of your theme.

Comment: I cleared cache already, also cloudflare cache, but it's still there. Headers.php also checked but there is nothing

Comment: You need to login to your server and use `grep` to find which of your plugins or theme files is improperly adding the fonts to the header, since it's not using `wp_enqueue_style` otherwise it would have a name.  IOW, you have to search for `Poppins` in your wp-content folder.

Comment: @HowardE I already downloaded whole backup to computer, and searched in every files to find googleapi instances and where I found them, already deleted, but still loading

Comment: Then it's cached. I see you said you already cleared it. But you must be missing one. Another long shot would be the wp database

Comment: Are you using another service like ezoic. If so there is also a purge cache feature in these services. Kindly check it to.

Comment: I cleared everything tons of times disabled all plugins changed theme but its still there, no I am not using any services